# How to create a container for data of different types in Java?

Tags: javascript, java, design-patterns

I'm trying to figure out what is the right Java code structure of a feature written in JavaScript.

I have several classes each of them should handle its method calls and store related data. Each class processes data for different ids (some kind of `containerId`). Data values are of different types:

```
// javascript
class A {
  constructor() {
    this._containers = new Map();
  }

  method1(id, data) {
    // ensure that a container for <id> exists
    const container = this._containers.get(id);
    container.set('hello', 'world');
  }

  method2(id, data) {
    // ensure that a container for <id> exists
    const container = this._containers.get(id);
    container.set('prop', 1);
  }

  method3(id, data) {
    const container = this._containers.get(id); // in this case no need to ensure
    container.set('some', 1.0);
  }
}

class B {
  constructor() {
    this._containers = new Map();
  }

  method1(id, data) {
    // ensure that a container for <id> exists
    const container = this._containers.get(id);
    container.put({ prop1: 'value1', prop2: 0 }); // this is actually not allowed in js, pseudo-code
  }
}
```

I'd like to remove code duplication (and also the responsibility of data storing management) with composition. Moving all store logic in a separate class, e.g. `DataHolder`. I just want to call `dataHolder.add(containerId, key, value);` which will check that a container exists and add key, value to it.

Java `DataHolder` could have an underlying storage as a `Map<String, ?>`. Due to method overloading I could define different variations of an `add` method:

```
// java
public class DataHolder {
  private Map<Integer, Map<String, ?>> containers = new HashMap<>();
  // ...
  add(int containerId, String key, ? value) {}
  add(int containerId, ? value) {} // it could take container.size() as a key
}
```

How do I define this `?` in `DataHolder` so that it handles everything correctly. If it's an `Object` how does `A` class know which type a value is? `instanceof` seems a bad idea. (When an `A` instance decides that it got the last chunk of data it should create a new Record for example with collected values).

If it's not the way a Java code is written, so what is the way?

Another approach could be to create `AContainers` class which holds a map of `A` instances (for each id) with all fields defined inside `A` class. But I don't like this approach because in that case `AContainers` should proxy all method calls to `A` instance (and also have some knowledge when `A` is done). For each algorithm `A`, `B`, ..., `Z` there will be 1 additional class. (`2*N` classes instead of `N`). And it should anyway implement the logic of creating an `A` instance on event (which contradicts the initial intent to move the creation logic outside the processors).

Answer (score 0):

```
// Java generics may be of help
public class DataHolder<T> {
    private Map<Integer, Map<String, T>> containers = new HashMap<>();

    add(int containerId, String key, T value) {}
    add(int containerId, T value) {} // it could take container.size() as a key
}
```

Comment: It could help if data contained values of the same type. What to do if for example `A` class data is `{ "initial": true, "amount": 33, "timestamp": 17773}`? And this key/values are collected one after another during calls to different methods of `A` instance.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).